# How to use set up Heroku Integration with PyCharm

Tags: heroku, pycharm

So, I've download the Heroku Integration, with PyCharm 2.7.2. I've put in the API key, added an app with a name I chose. I want to create just a basic django app on a heroku free account. So, what do I do now? Could someone please give me some basic instructions as to how you get started with actually uploading all the stuff in your project to Heroku?

Answer (score -5):

Not sure about the pycharm integration, but the easy answer is git push to heroku.

When using pycharm, I just do Menu >> VCS >> Git >> Push.  Then if heroku is not your default remote (origin), check the box for push to alternate remote/branch.  I choose heroku and master and away it goes!

Comment: Not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Could you be more specific then? Anything that isn't in the documentation? - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python

Comment: Well, I was actually talking about the plugin for intelliJ. There _is_ one, but it needs some setting up. Since I don't know anything about it, I was wondering if anyone _had_ used it before, to give me a method.

Comment: please delete this answer, it really does nothing to answer the user's question. "how do set up the Heroku Integration ?" > "I use git to deploy my projects" ...

Comment: It there a tutorial one can follow to show how to do this from within Pycharm in a secure manner (protecting the keys)?